# Is there a jQuery alternative to a drop-down box that could contain over 100,00 values?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I have a drop down box that has worked until now. New data in our system means that having a drop down box on a particular screen is no longer feasible, because it would contain tens or hundreds of thousands of values.

I still need to have just one value selected by the user. Is there a better control I can use for this? Such as something that would allow the user to reduce the potential dataset by typing the first few characters?

Comment: how about autocomplete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use one of the autocomplete plugins:

[JQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

[Devbridge Autocomplete](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/)

[jQuery Autocomplete Mod](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a plugin like [FCBKcomplete](http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html). It generates a Facebook like search option.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the last yayQuery podcasts mentioned a website that had a listbox that was populated as the user scrolled through it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good one:
http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

However, it can be a bit inflexible sometimes. I wrote an xa.js fork of it from scratch at:
https://github.com/skippychalmers/xa-chosen